Excel formula: how to find if a value is within a range of thresholds, & then return the corresponding row
I'm trying to calculate my student loan (lol). Below are the first few rows of legit data from my government, which don't seem to follow any pattern whatsoever.



Threshold ($)
Repayment rate (%)




51,550
0


59,519
1


63,090
2


66,876
2.5


70,889
3


...
...



If my income is less than a certain threshold (first column), my repayment rate will be the corresponding value in the second column.
For example:

Income = 50,000 < 51,550, so repayment rate = 0%.
Income = 51,550 < 59,519, so repayment rate = 1%.
Income = 59,518 < 59,519, so repayment rate = 1%.

I want to have a formula that returns the corresponding repayment rate for my income.

Because this involves comparing one value to 20 rows of data, I really hope that there can be a cleaner solution instead of a bunch of ifs. I only know the basics of Excel formulae, so I need help & guidance with this. Thanks a lot!

Is there anything you've already tried? I think an XLOOKUP can work.

I've tried solutions involving index online but I don't fully understand how to use it... I only know vlookup :') I'll look into xlookup, thanks a lot!

For future referene, try to involve your failed attempts, it gives us information about where your cells are located, or how your tables are called. Or we might find an error and that might fix the issue aswell.

A simple vlookup() like so:
VLOOKUP(E4,$A$3:$B$7,2,1)


Thanks so much! I didn't know vlookup can be used outside of exact matches.

@Vero that is due to the 4th optional argument 0 for exact match, 1 for up to. Check out match() - has -1, 0 and 1 for controlling the behaviour.

Here's one way to do it using XLOOKUP:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE , C1 < A2:A5 , B1:B5 , "Not Found")

How this works:
You're looking for a TRUE in a 'temporary generated matrix', which is C1 < A2:A5
Where C1 is the cell in which you input your income.
A2:A5 is the column containing the thresholds and B2:B5 is payment rate column.
The "Not found" is optional, but it's the result given should your formula not find a solution (if you leave it blank, it will produce an error).
